# Excel Module - RGB to XYZ color

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a module in excel allowing me to convert an RGB color to XYZ using the following "neutral programming function" from EasyRGB (http://www.easyrgb.com/en/math.php):

```
var_R = ( sR / 255 )
var_G = ( sG / 255 )
var_B = ( sB / 255 )

if ( var_R > 0.04045 ) var_R = ( ( var_R + 0.055 ) / 1.055 ) ^ 2.4
else                   var_R = var_R / 12.92
if ( var_G > 0.04045 ) var_G = ( ( var_G + 0.055 ) / 1.055 ) ^ 2.4
else                   var_G = var_G / 12.92
if ( var_B > 0.04045 ) var_B = ( ( var_B + 0.055 ) / 1.055 ) ^ 2.4
else                   var_B = var_B / 12.92

var_R = var_R * 100
var_G = var_G * 100
var_B = var_B * 100

X = var_R * 0.4124 + var_G * 0.3576 + var_B * 0.1805
Y = var_R * 0.2126 + var_G * 0.7152 + var_B * 0.0722
Z = var_R * 0.0193 + var_G * 0.1192 + var_B * 0.9505
```

The issue is that i'm not familiar enough with VBA to get it to work as an excel module/formula. It will take the sR, sG and sB values from cells B through D of each row (eg. row 1 - sR = B3, sG = C3 and sB = D3). Perform the above calculations and then output XYZ values.

I then want the X, Y, Z values to output in their own cells on the same row as the original RGB values (eg. row 1 - X = I3, Y = J3 and Z = K3).

Comment: You want to define this as a function. Then you can use that function in your workbook. Then your choice would be to either define 3 functions for X,Y and Z, or define 1 function that returns the values comma seperated. Here is some info on how to make a user defined function: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/user-defined-function.html

Comment: So what is your actual question? You didn't ask one yet. Also you should [edit] your question and answer the following questions to make it easier to help you: Where did you get stuck, any error messages (if yes which and where)? What is working in your code and what doesn't work? Also your code is only a part, please show the whole function/procedure.